# How is possible that "display: flex" and "align-items: center" do not work anymore on my iphone?

Tags: ios, css, iphone, webkit, flexbox

Hello guys is really strange what happened to me today ...
I'm working on a code to create submenus, and I used the property

```
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
```

in this way the voices of the various sections (tags li) are centered vertically.
I have used these properties many times before for other codes and they have always worked correctly. As always, I check the code on my mac, on the iPhone 5, on firefox and chrome.

But as soon as I see the file via my iphone 5 (version 8.3) I was shocked .... the properties were not working. I have displayed the old files and even with them the same problem occurred.

[image]

The amazing thing is that the mc works wonderfully well with the iPhone 5 to my brother (updated to version 9.x):

[image]

I do not understand .... but how is that possible?

It 'a bug? or my iphone is broken?

Comment: Add vendor prefix  `-webkit-align-items:center;`

Comment: @LuisP.A. wow you are right... but how is possible ?  before worked

Comment: `-webkit-` prefixes are no longer required for flex layouts as of iOS 9+

Answer (score 34):

There is a flexbox [bug](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs#9-some-html-elements-cant-be-flex-containers) in Safari:

> The `<button>` and `<fieldset>` elements can't be flex containers in Safari.

Solution: use a different wrapping element, e.g. an `<a>` tag.

If you can't or don't want to change the element, you can fix it using [box-orient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-orient):

```
display: -webkit-box;
-webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
```

Comment: The amount of times i come back to this answer is stupid.
Really thankful for the answer! 

Comment: This works with the flex box and orientation, but i cannot use align items og justify-content, even with vendor prefixes

Comment: Here is a useful link for those facing cross-browser issues: https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs#9-some-html-elements-cant-be-flex-containers

Answer (score 10):

For me to get vertical and horizontal central alignment across Safari and Chrome on iOS and desktop I had to use:

```
display: flex;
display: -webkit-flex;
justify-content: center;
-webkit-justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
-webkit-align-items: center;
```

Answer (score 5):

[Should I Prefix](http://shouldiprefix.com/#flexbox)  recommends that flexbox still be vendor-prefixed. Anecdotally, I would say that it really only needs to be prefixed on Safari.

This means not *only* vendor prefixing your display settings, but all Flex box properties:

```
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: flex;
 -webkit-align-items: center;
 align-items: center;
```