# Background image for mobile devices not staying centered

Tags: html, css

For some reason, my background image is not staying centered when viewing from my phone, but when viewing mobile screen sizes from my desktop browser using the toggle device toolbar in Chrome Dev Tools it stays centered.

```css
body { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
h1 { 
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: "PPWoodland-Bold";
  color: #18454A;
  animation: drop 1s linear; 
  padding: 1rem 0 0;
  margin: 0;
}
#banner {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;

    background: url("https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0099/7795/4368/files/banner-stripped.png?v=1633873595") no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

@media (max-width: 749px) {
    #banner h1 { font-size: 32px; }
}
```

```html
<div id="banner-wrap">
  <div id="banner">
    <h1 id='banner-title'><span>Lorem Ipsum</span><span>dolor sit amet</span></h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: And your phone is?

Comment: My phone is not showing the center of the image. All it's showing is pink background.

Comment: What is the make and model of the phone :D ? If it's an Iphone, it might be following different standards, than an Android/Chrome phone.. Browser in the phone also matters. If it's an old Android phone, it could be missing browser functionality standards.. so in your CSS you would need to cover for these.

Comment: iPhone 11 using chrome also used Safari on a newer iPhone

Comment: does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33084810/how-is-possible-that-display-flex-and-align-items-center-do-not-work-anymo ?

Comment: hmm doesn't appear to be working. I added this to the banner-wrap element. 

display: -webkit-box;
-webkit-box-orient: horizontal;

Comment: Is this a flexbox issue though?