# Flexbox align-items and justify-content end not working in Safari MacOs

Tags: css, google-chrome, debugging, flexbox, safari

I have this code in my CSS for a section

```
align-items: end;
justify-content: end;
```

It works well on Chrome MacOs but on Safari the elements are not aligned from the bottom.
Does someone know why?

Link: https://q6demo.squarespace.com/homepage#our-6-step-process-section

[image][image]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I have used this and it is working

```
-webkit-justify-content: flex-end;
align-items: flex-end;
-webkit-align-items: flex-end;
```

Source: [How is possible that "display: flex" and "align-items: center" do not work anymore on my iphone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33084810/how-is-possible-that-display-flex-and-align-items-center-do-not-work-anymo)

Comment: Wow this worked perfectly for me.  Thank you

Comment: Great! I'm glad it works for you!

Comment: The solution is simply to use `flex-end` instead of `end`. The prefixes are not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

My friend, I think it's because of browser support

[Support metadata for browsers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJPvE.png)

Information can be found here
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

Comment: I have tried to use prefixed values and it is the same.
The latest Safari supports Flexbox by default.